# Why are my SQL SUMs not coming back NULL when they include NULL values?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I use a CTE to calculate spans of time in a log as shown in this fiddle:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b99448/6

Note that one of the rows has a `NULL` value because that is the most recent log entry and no calculation could be made.

However, if I `SUM` these results the `NULL` is being treated as a zero:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b99448/4

How can I get this to stop ignoring NULL values?
I would expect the sum to be `NULL` since it is adding a `NULL` value.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain how I can improve the question?

Comment: This is how `sum()` (or any aggregate) is defined: they ignore `NULL` values. the sum of `1,2,null,3` is 1+2+3 = 6 - by definition in the SQL standard

Comment: [From the manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) "*SUM can be used with numeric columns only. **Null values are ignored***"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The aggregation functions ignore `NULL` values.  They are not treated as `0` -- the distinction is more important for `AVG()`, `MIN()`, and `MAX()`.  So, `SUM()` only returns `NULL` when all values are `NULL`.

If you want to get `NULL` back, here is a simple expression:

```
select (case when count(*) = count(a.DateTimeChangedUtc) and
                  count(*) = count(b.DateTimeChangedUTC)
             then SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.DateTimeChangedUtc, b.DateTimeChangedUTC)) 
        end) AS TimeSpentSeconds
```

This returns `NULL` if either argument is ever `NULL`.